# What's A Good Real Time Html Editing Extension?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons

i always like to real-time edit a web page source in the browser and updated as i type, but firebug really sucks, i can't insert scripts in the current page, some times the changes i type aren't updated at all, Is there any robust firefox/chrome extension for that?

i try to temporarely edit/add code to an existing web page in the internet, not a local one

Thanks

Comment: Consider changing the title of your question to something less argumentative- otherwise it's likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hi, i always like to real-time edit a
>   web page source in the browser and
>   updated as i type, but firebug really
>   sucks, i can't insert scripts in the
>   current page, some times the changes i
>   type aren't updated at all, Is there
>   any robust firefox/chrome extension
>   for that?

It never behaves the way you mention, probably there is some other issue. Firebug seems to be the best bet out there so far.

> P.S. i try to temporarely edit an
>   existing web page in the internet, not
>   a local one

Yes, you can do that too.

Finally, here is the [community link](http://getfirebug.com/community) and possible solutions to various questions.

Comment: When i try to add < script src="xxx"></script > it doesn't works!

Comment: @David: Not sure but i think this is not allowed because of security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a built-in DOM Inspector, script editor/debugger; it comes with Webkit (what Chrome and Safari are built on).

Right click anywhere on the page and click on "Inspect Element". That will bring up your HTML that is currently on the page. You can double click any element and it will let you edit it.

This also has some pretty powerful features that you can use. These tutorials about [javascript debugging](http://blog.kapilchhabra.com/2008/09/google-chrome-and-javascripthtml-debugging/) and the [general overview](http://dev.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial) of the developer tools are really helpful.